# Feedback tool with dynamic recipients

Tags: forms, survey

I'm looking for some tool like Google Forms but in which :

- The user who would setup/edit survey questions could be different than the one receiving the survey results; for example, **user1** would setup the survey but only **user2** would have access to the results;
- The recipient of the survey results could be changed whenever needed;

**Context:** In my company each week a different person makes a presentation about some topic. The tool above would be used to give feedback to a different person each week.

Comment: Who is changing the permissions? User3?

Comment: @Markus: user1 ;)

Comment: In your case it is a little bit strange that the creator (user1) has no access to the results but can change the permission to get access. But maybe the feedback / idea collection of https://pollunit.com can help you. Admin permissions can be shared via "admin link". A real (multiple questions) survey is planned for end of this year.